# Different best fit, and obtain p-value from regression in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, lm

I have this graph, from package `car`, figure 1:
[image]

The code is:

```
scatterplot(istat_22 ~ vpa_cnr_2,grid=F, smooth=F)
```

But if i want the p-value of the regression line, and r and r^2,how i can obtained it and plot them on the graph?
Substancially i would the equation of the straight line and the value of the statistic.
Another question is, why if I plot with `lm`, like:

```
plot(vpa_cnr_2,istat_22)
abline(lm(vpa_cnr_2 ~ istat_22),col="red")
```

the straight line is not the same of figure 1 (see the figure 2)?

figure 2
[image]

Yes i know, it depend from intercept, but R don't find the best fit with function `lm`?

Comment: `car::scatterplot` returns either the list of points (via `id.method`, et al) or `NULL`; it does not offer returning any of the summary statistics. As you suspected, you'll need to perform the regression yourself. (If you look at the source for `car::scatterplot.default` and ultimately `car:::reg`, you'll see that the summary statistics are not retained.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically if you want to extract values from your linear regression one can use `summary`.

```
#use str(summary(x)) to explore the other useful pieces of information
x <- lm(istat_22 ~ vpa_cnr_2)
summary(x)$r.squared
summary(x)$adj.r.squared
summary(x)$coefficients[2,4] # p-value
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use Adjusted R-squared and overall p-value of the model if you would like show them in the graph, which can be directly obtained or calculated from the summary of the model.

`summary <- summary(lm(istat_22 ~ via_cnr_2))
 adjRsq <- summary$adj.r.squared`

You can not get the overall p-value directly from the summary but you can calculate from the F-statistics, and here is how you can calculate it:

`fStat <- summary$statistic
 pValue <- pf(fStat[1], fStat[2], fStat[3], lower.tail = F)`

You can refer to this link: [Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) for how to label them in ggplot. As for why the regression line does not seem correct, it's because your variables are reverted in lm formula. 
`abline(lm(istat_22 ~ vpa_cnr_2),col="red")`

Comment: Yes, for the second question you are right...ups...but for p-value? (question one)

Comment: Just reedited my answer, hope it answered your question.